# Logging value of checkboxes in console

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want the console to log every time a checkbox gets checked or unchecked. What is wrong with my current approach? This prints nothing out to the console.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    console.log("loaded");
});

var $filterCheckboxes = $('input[type="checkbox"]');
$filterCheckboxes.on('change', function() {
  $filterCheckboxes.filter(":checked").each(function() {
    console.log(this.value);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="">
  <div class="checkbox-group">
    <input type="checkbox" name="name_1" value="value1" id="id_1">
    <label for="name_1">
      <span class="check"></span>
      <span class="box"></span>
      Name 1
    </label>
  </div>
</li>
```

Comment: Typo, change `var $filteredCheckboxes` to `var $filterCheckboxes`

Comment: Rectified it in my code, but it still doesn't work

Comment: After you fixed the typo, I've converted to a snippet where it works fine.

Comment: I see it is working in your code snippet even

Comment: @ParitoshLouhan see my comment above yours... :)

Comment: So what is different about the code that works in the snipplet and your actual code that does not work? Right now it runs, we need more info to figure out why it does not. your checkboxes dynamic, does the code run before the elements are rendered? Where is the code at in the document?

Comment: oh okay, thans :) Why didn't we put up in answer? @freedomn-m

Comment: That's very odd, it doesn't print out in my console. I have a console.log before this snippet which prints out just fine

Comment: @ParitoshLouhan Short answer: We don't create answers for typos / not produced in the question.  We vote close typo.  Long answer: giving OP a chance to explain themselves / provide more details / review their code before voting close; an answer that says "works fine here" doesn't help anyone.

Comment: "*I have a console.log before this snippet*" - so you have other code not included here.   Could be any reason then.  Please read [mcve] and update the snippet in the question to *demonstrate* the problem.  Some code that clearly works (minus typo) won't help us to help you.

Comment: @epascarello makes some good points: try wrapping your code inside doc.ready:  `$(function() { var $filterCheckboxes = $('input[type="checkbox"]'); ... etc })`.   Do you add checkboxes to your page *after* this code runs (even in doc ready)?

Comment: I have updated the code. I will try what you suggest

Comment: `$(document).ready(function(){
    console.log("loaded");
});` does not going to make any difference for `var $filterCheckboxes = $('input[type="checkbox"]');`

Comment: Wrapping the `var $filterCheckboxes` snippet inside document.ready worked. I don't understand why this would be the case, but it worked

Comment: The reason is that the code is executed before the document is ready. Meaning, it makes the variable, but since the elements aren't rendered yet, the variable will be empty. In almost all cases, wrap your function in `$(function() { ... your code here ... });`

Answer (score 1):

```js
let fieldnamelist = [];
        $(".fieldnames").click(function()
        {
           let fieldnamecheck = $(this).is(":checked");
           let fieldnames = $(this).val();
           if(fieldnamecheck==true)
           {
               fieldnamelist.push(fieldnames);
               console.log(fieldnamelist);
           }
           else
           {
               for(var i =0;i<3;i++)
               {
                   if(fieldnamelist[i]==fieldnames)
                   {
                       fieldnamelist.splice(i, 1);
                       console.log(fieldnamelist);
                   }
               }
           }
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="fieldnames" value="One"> One
        
                <input type="checkbox" class="fieldnames" value="Two"> Two
```

Answer (score 1):

You actually don't need to use the `filter()` function, Try this:

```
var $filterCheckboxes = $('input[type="checkbox"]');
$filterCheckboxes.on('change', function(){
        console.log($(this).val());
});
```

The `val()`function gets the current checked value of a set of checkboxes.
And you might wanna specify the set of checkboxes you want to log by using the `name` attribute on them, e.g:

```
name="common_boxes"
```

And it's also a good practice not to mix some components of `Javascript` and `jQuery` together,
Like the `element.value` should be replaced with `element.val()`, just as the above snippet does.
And again I emphasize, its just a good practice to do that but you can just however use as you prefer